# VBA copy certain cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem. I have three columns in Excel like that

```
A               B        C
13/03/2015  GXH15   
16/03/2015  GXH15   
17/03/2015  GXH15   
18/03/2015  GXH15   
19/03/2015  GXH15   
20/03/2015  GXH15   17/03/2015
23/03/2015  GXM15   
24/03/2015  GXM15
```

The formula in C is `=IF(Ob61=b62,"",a61-3)`. So I try to write a code which takes all values in B and copies them in another column by leaving also the empty cells, which I do not need.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Roll()

Dim RollDate As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range


Set RollDate = Range("B7:B2500")

i = 1
For Each cell In RollDate
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
    cell.Value.Copy Range("X7")
    cell.Value = i
    i = i + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

This is what I have written, but it does not work.

### Update

Thank you for the answers, but they still do not work as I want. I will try to make things more clear

```
A               B        C
13/03/2015  GXH15   
16/03/2015  GXH15   
17/03/2015  GXH15   
18/03/2015  GXH15   
19/03/2015  GXH15   
20/03/2015  GXH15   17/03/2015
23/03/2015  GXM15   
24/03/2015  GXM15
20/03/2015  GXH15   xx/03/2015
23/03/2015  GXM15   
24/03/2015  GXM15
```

My aim is to have then in colum X just the values from C

```
X
17/03/2015
xx/03/2015
.
.
.
etc.
```

Comment: What does _"it does not work"_ mean?

Comment: Nothing happens, when I execute the code

Comment: see my answer. let me know

Comment: In your code you refer to the `ActiveCell` but that never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited after OP's clarification:

```
Sub Roll2()
    With Range("b7:b2500")
        .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy '<--| consider cells with number value resulting from a formula
        .Offset(, 22).PasteSpecial SkipBlanks:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @AntonPetrov, did you get through it?

Comment: No I did not. I receive a mistake in the third row

Comment: what kind of "mistake"?

Comment: "No cells were found." I tried it with both nuber and date formatting.

Comment: you said that column C cells have a formula (namely `=IF(Ob61=b62,"",a61-3)`, does it still hold true?

Comment: Yes its =IF(b61=b62,"",a61-3)

Comment: what is the `ActiveSheet` when you run the macro? You can get that by placing a breakpoint at `With Range("b7:b2500")` and when your macro stops there you type `?Activesheet.Name` in the Immediate Window and press return

Comment: .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy

Comment: after `With Range("b7:b2500")` place the statement `.Offset(,1).Select`, place a breakpoint at `.Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy` and when your code stops there switch to excel and check if selected cells are the ones you exptected in the sheet you expected

Answer (score 0):

Also with some guesswork, as not clear what you're asking, but with a slightly different interpretation to the above answer.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Roll()

Dim RollDate As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set RollDate = Range("B7:B2500")

i = 1
For Each cell In RollDate.Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
    Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = cell.Value
    cell.Value = i
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```